# Specifying relative path to :r command in sqlcmd mode

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

A) Suppose you have four `.sql` files `(script1.sql,script2.sql,script3.sql,script4.sql )` in say in a folder `c:\scripts`.

B) Create a main script file (`Main.sql`) with the following, please note I have given relative path for scripts.

```
:r script1.sql
:r script2.sql
:r script3.sql
:r script4.sql
```

Save the `Main.sql` in `c:\scripts itself`.

C) Create a batch file named "`ExecuteScripts.bat`" with the following:-

```
SQLCMD -E -d<YourDatabaseName> -ic:\Scripts\Main.sql
PAUSE
```

When I run the batch file, its unable to script1.sql file. When i give full path `C:\scripts\script1.sql`, it works fine but I don't want to hardcode the path here.

Is it possible to achieve this using sqlcmd?

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\scripts"
SQLCMD -E -d<YourDatabaseName> -iMain.sql
popd
PAUSE
```

Or if all the sql scripts are in the same folder as your batch script, then:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
SQLCMD -E -d<YourDatabaseName> -iMain.sql
popd
PAUSE
```

The last version allows your scripts to run properly, no matter where they reside.

Comment: `pushd "%~f0"` does not work for me, but `pushd "%~dp0"` does.

Comment: @Nathan - You are absolutely correct. That was a sloppy mistake on my part. Thanks. I've corrected the answer with an edit.

Answer (score 0):

What about using complete paths, but creating file `Main.sql` dynamically?

Batch file which expects the 4 script files in folder of the batch file and creates there also `Main.sql`.

```
@echo off
set "BatchFolder=%~dp0"
(   echo :r %BatchFolder%script1.sql
    echo :r %BatchFolder%script2.sql
    echo :r %BatchFolder%script3.sql
    echo :r %BatchFolder%script4.sql
)>"%BatchFolder%Main.sql"
sqlcmd.exe -E -d "YourDatabaseName" -i "%BatchFolder%Main.sql"
set "BatchFolder="
pause
```

Open a command prompt window and run there `call /?`. The help of this command is output in the window explaining `%~dp0` which means drive and path of argument 0 ending with a backslash without surrounding quotes. Argument 0 on running of a batch file is the name of the batch file.

Running in command prompt window `set /?` results in getting help of command **set** displayed, listing on last help page some special environment variables defined dynamic on running a batch file. The first one listed is `%CD%` which means current directory.

So instead of working with folder of batch file, it is also possible to work with current folder on batch execution.

```
@echo off
set "CurrentFolder=%CD%\"
(   echo :r %CurrentFolder%script1.sql
    echo :r %CurrentFolder%script2.sql
    echo :r %CurrentFolder%script3.sql
    echo :r %CurrentFolder%script4.sql
)>"%CurrentFolder%Main.sql"
sqlcmd.exe -E -d "YourDatabaseName" -i "%CurrentFolder%Main.sql"
set "CurrentFolder="
pause
```

The folder path referenced by `%CD%` does not end with a backslash like the folder path returned by `%~dp0` which is the reason for backslash after `%CD%` on second line.